# Private videos in Cordova web view

Tags: ios, cordova, token, private

I would like to play videos inside an IOS web view with Cordova.

Videos must be available only inside this app.
I don't have any domain to restrict access, because it's a web view inside a native app.

Is there a way to use HTTPS with Javascript to authenticate with an API token, then play each video with this token?

Can anyone provide a specific script example to do the job?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do this in such a way that someone could not break it because an attacker could install a man-in-the-middle server with a certificate created using their own certificate authority and then sniff the data and use it outside the application.

However you could make it more difficult, by creating "single use" keys that you send to the device using the notification service every time a key is used, you invalidate it and create a new key for the next use. This would mean that someone trying to get around the system would find it very difficult to have more than one client using the content at any given time.

Given that that is the best you can do, why not simply have users authenticate themselves and not allow multiple sessions to be active for the same user?